# Does NetBeans have an analog of the eclipse memory analyzer tool?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Does NetBeans have an analog of the eclipse memory analyzer tool? I have recently watched a lecture on youtube/oracleLearning "From Java Code to Java Heap: Understanding the Memory Usage of Your Application". In it he demonstrated using the memory analyzer tool eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [heapwalker](https://profiler.netbeans.org/docs/help/6.0/heapwalker.html) to analyze hprof dumps through netbeans. It is available under Profile -> Load Heap Dump